# How to repair hardware having dificulties to turn ON PC

Tags: motherboard, power-supply, power

I have a very strange problem that gives me troubles almost every time I try to turn on mi PC. Yes, almost, not always.

When I push the power button, my computer acts like nothing happened. Sometimes it turns on a few minutes later after i pushed the start button, other times, many hours later.

I found a workaround that consists in remove the ATX power cable from the mother board, put it again, and push the power button. I have to try that many times until it works and my PC finally turns on. In every try, when I pull the ATX cable diagonally disconnecting the upper pins first, my PC "tries" to turn on, giving a flash in the lights and a small impulse to the fans. Just like it were normally energized for ~0.5 seconds.

I don't know how to solve this strange problem, I don't know if the problem come from the mother board or the power supply. Sometimes I think it may be a broken condenser but i don't know how to probe it, i don't see any phisical damage.

The motherboard is an Asus Maximus VIII Hero and the power supply a cooler master V1000 (80+ gold)

I recorded this video to better explain the problem.

https://youtu.be/sRlI241SxDQ

I would really appreciate any help.

**EDIT:** I have measured the electric outlet. I have 0.3 VAC ground to neutral, 224 VAC neutral to phase and 224 VAC ground to phase.
Also I have checked both extremes of the EATX cable. All pins looks perfectly ok in both extremes, there is no visible minimal damage. In the PSU, this cable is connected to 18P M/B and 10P M/B. When I diagonally pull the right side of the cable from the 10P M/B connector, I got the same effect than pulling the upper side of the EATX cable from the MB like shown in the video.

Comment: It sounds like your PSU may have drained just enough wattage to have problems supplying enough power. You can try a full power reset to see if it allows the energy to flow better. To do this, unplug the powercord from the back of your pc, with the powercord unplugged, press and hold the on-off button at the front of your pc for 30 seconds. This will make all residual energy in capacitors drain. Now, if your PSU has a power switch, set it to the off position, then plugin the power cable, then switch it back to on, and try to power on the pc.

Comment: Also, it will help immensely if you plugin the system into an outlet that is grounded. If you have the computer in a power brick with on/off switch, it may help to keep the powerbrick in the on switch all the time, so that when you turn off the computer, it keeps being connected to the wall.

Comment: The first thing I would do is purchase a new power cable for your computer.  I would then purchase a new replacement power cable compatible with your PSU.  If both those fail to solve the problem it's time to replace the PSU entirely.  **What you describe is dangerous.**  Your motherboard does not have a "condenser" by the way.

Comment: @Ramhound why do you think the problem may be the cable? after my PC is turned on, it works all normally with no time limit. The cable seems ok, i don't see any damage on it. Coud you explain further please?

Comment: @Clamari - Here are the reasons I suspect it's the cable.  1. A cable is extremely cheap solution to try.  2.  Your PC does not turn on, 100% of the time, when you press the appropriate button.  3.  The behavior you describe with the cable while you disconnect it sounds dangerous, it should not be turning on, the fact it does attempt to turn itself on is concerning.  4. **My 2.8 decades of experience working with computers, indicates the problem, is either with the cable or the PSU itself.**

Comment: @Ramhound My PSU is fully modular. Could I discard that the cable is the problem if I disconnect the cable and test that the continuity is ok in both sides of every pin? I have knowledge of electricity. I know a cable is cheap but it is neither easy nor fast to find and buy cable for me. BTW it relieves me to know that the MB is not the problem. Thank you very much for your help.

Comment: I didn’t say your motherboard wasn’t the problem. I said I suspect the cable and/or PSU over the motherboard.  It certainly could be the motherboard.

Comment: @LPChip It makes sense to me what you say. The electrical installation here is not good and maybe the ground is not properly connected. My computer keeps connected to an outlet 24/7. Do you think that a deficient connected ground in the electrical installation may be the problem? I just measured the voltage in the outlet and it is 221 VAC. It seems ok to me

Comment: @LPChip I have measured the outlet. I have 0.3 VAC ground to neutral, 224 VAC neutral to phase and, 224 VAC ground to phase. Everything seems to be ok. Do you have any additional feedback?

Comment: @LPChip I did exactly what you suggested in your first comment but all reamins the same.

Comment: Moved to chat https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/105993/discussion-between-clamari-and-ramhound

Comment: I agree with Ramhound here, though I doubt the cables are the problem. I have heard enough times that a PSU can lose its strength over time, especially if the socket it is connected to is not stable, which is the case as you mentioned. If the PSU is too weak, it can't deliver the initial peak required by the system until enough electricity is already inside the system to lower the peak. Given that this is not healthy for the motherboard, I would recommend replacing the PSU.

Comment: Finally, the problem was the power supply. I just bought another new and all is working like a charm again. Thank you very much @Ramhound and LPChip

Answer (score 1):

Finally, the problem was the power supply. I just bought another new and all is working like a charm again. The power supply was 7 yeras old.